# Overriding global CSS to remove * Selector

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the below CSS code in a file. I can't edit this file as it's part of the core framework.

```
*,body,html{font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif!important}
```

I am using Fontawesome icon fonts and due to use of `*` in the CSS file, makes all fontawesome icons to appear as boxes.

Is it possible to override the above property to reflect as below in other external CSS file which I can control.

```
body,html{font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif!important}
```

The above code changes does not seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whatch this code, you can  try to set all variables that you want to set by default, but remember the style need to be loaded after the font awesome style
https://plnkr.co/edit/xoUooxNWoboEx8htKLUl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you can include CSS somewhere properly, just add the line you want to use so it's included after the one you show from the framework. Last CSS rule wins.

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes and it seem to work as the problem is specific to Fontawesome.

Answer (score 0):

As the issue is more specific to Fontawesome, based on other answers in SO, I made the below changes and it works now.

```
*,body,html{font-family:'FontAwesome','Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important}
```

I added FontAwesome to the list of font-family.

Thanks for giving the direction.